# Probability that the sum of three (or any number) of independent but not identical exponential RV is greater than a number?

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, exponential-distribution, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

> Suppose $X_1$, $X_2$ are i.i.d. exponential with rate $\lambda = 3$ and  $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ are i.i.d. exponential with $\lambda = 4$. Find $P(X1+2X2+Y1>3)$.

This was only part of the question, but this was a part that I had no idea how to do. Obviously, $X_1 + 2X_2 + Y_1$ are all independent so this ends up being an $\exp(3)+\exp(3/2)+\exp(4)$, and we are trying to find the probability that the sum of three independent exponential variables is greater than $3$. My initial thought was to use some kind of order statistics, where I find that the minimum of the three variables is greater than $3$. However, I then realized that was completely wrong since it is the sum of three exponential random variables. Does anybody know how to proceed with such a question?

Comment: Look up the distribution for a sum of exponential distributions. By this I mean $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are all exponential with different rates, their sum $X_1+X_2+X_3$ is a new random variable and has a particular distribution ( look it up and the answer will be easy).

Comment: @Monty This is only the case when the $X_i$ have the same mean. Otherwise the density is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\mu)$ are independent where $\lambda\ne\mu$, then the density of $Z:=X+Y$ can be found by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_Z(t) &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_X(s)f_Y(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mu e^{-\mu(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \lambda\mu e^{-\mu t} \int_0^t e^{-(\lambda +\mu)s}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \frac{\lambda\mu}{\mu-\lambda} (e^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\mu t}).
\end{align}
Moreover, if $c>0$ then for all $t>0$ we have
$$
\{cX\leqslant t\} = \left\{X\leqslant \frac tc\right\},
$$
and a quick computation shows that $cX$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\frac\lambda c$. So we can use convolution to find the distribution of $Z:=X_1+2X_2+Y_1$; assuming $\mathbb E[X_1] = \frac1\lambda$ and $\mathbb E[Y_1]=\frac1\mu$, we find that
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac{\lambda  \mu  e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t} \left(\lambda  e^{\mu  t}-2 \lambda  e^{\frac{\lambda  t}{2}+\mu  t}+2 \mu  e^{\frac{\lambda  t}{2}+\mu  t}+\lambda  e^{\lambda  t}-2 \mu  e^{\mu  t}\right)}{(\lambda -2 \mu ) (\lambda -\mu )}.
$$
From this we find
$$
\mathbb P(Z>3) = \int_3^\infty f_Z(t)\ \mathsf dt = \frac{e^{-3 (\lambda +\mu )} \left(e^{3 \lambda } \lambda ^2+e^{3 \mu } \mu  \left(-4 e^{\frac{3 \lambda }{2}} (\lambda -\mu )+\lambda -2 \mu \right)\right)}{(\lambda -2 \mu ) (\lambda -\mu )}.
$$
Substituting $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=4$, the above is
$$
\frac15 e^{-12}\left(4 e^3 \left(4 e^{9/2}-5\right)+9\right)\approx 0.0350662.
$$
I sincerely hope your instructor does not expect you to do computations like these by hand...

Comment: Wow, thanks for the really detailed answer! I am taking a stochastic processes course, but I don't think convolution was covered by the professor so I guess this was more of a self-learning type of question. Thank you for the response!